# How to check clicked item is parent item in Treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview

To get the child items as string i used the following code

```
private void treeview1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            if (treeview1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                Animal bar = (Animal)treeview1.SelectedItem;
                string str = bar.Name;
                int boxty = bar.BoxType;
                int boxno = bar.BoxNo;
            }

        }
```

It works fine .But when i click on parent(instead of + sign),it goes to this code and shows error.Ofcourse im casting SelectedItem to my List-Animal.
But i dont want this.I have to check,whether the clciked item is parent,if it is so then i will skip this coding.Only when i click the child items it will go to this coding.
How can i do that?How can i identify the selected item is parent.

Comment: what error do you get when this code is run?  is it producing an error because when you click on the + symbol you don't actually have anything selected in your treeview?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal' to type 'GroupingTreeView.Animal'.
Im getting this error.
When i press + sign,it doesn't go to that function.Its just expanding child items.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code of line

```
treeview1.Items.IndexOf(treeview1.SelectedItem)
```

It returns -1 when we select the cild items,and it returns 1,2.etc,depends upon which parent item is get clicked.

So i used this to check whether the clciked item is child.

```
 if (treeview1.Items.IndexOf(treeview1.SelectedItem) == -1)
                {
                    Animal bar = (Animal)treeview1.SelectedItem;
                    string str = bar.Name;
                    int boxty = bar.BoxType;
                    int boxno = bar.BoxNo;
                }
```